# Ошибка в android studio "RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity"

Tags: android-studio

Вот, что пишет студия:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.bignerdtanch.android.criminalintent/com.bignerdtanch.android.criminalintent.CrimeListActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.bignerdtanch.android.criminalintent.CrimeListActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.bignerdtanch.android.criminalintent-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.bignerdtanch.android.criminalintent-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]

Но как всё было. Позавчера перенёс папку проекта в другое место, но проект был рабочим, вчера открываю студию, запускаю, сама студия пишет ошибку, что не какие-то проблемы с установкой, попробуйте переустановить, или что-то такое. Но переустановка не помогала, погуглил, посоветовали очистить проект и собрать заново, не помогло, приложение устанавливалось, но вылетало. Вернул проект на прежнее место и всё заработало. Сегодня опять тоже самое, но проект уже не трогал и вчера был рабочим

Comment: Помимо очистки проекта и удаления приложения с девайса можно попробовать `InstantRun` отключить в настройках студии

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!)) Заработало))

Comment: Я написал это в ответ - вы можете отметить его "верным", нажав на галочку слева от тела поста)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помимо очистки проекта и удаления приложения с девайса можно попробовать `InstantRun` отключить в настройках студии.

Последний иногда вызывает такие проблемы, т.к. студия не каждый раз пересобирает APK, но изменяет отдельные его части. В итоге могут возникнуть конфликты или APK может быть не полным, т.е. не рабочим.